# How to get the msbuild path returned from "nuget.exe restore"

Tags: git, msbuild, nuget, githooks

I'm new to using git hooks and now I'm trying to restore nuget packages for the projects in my solution and after that build the solution.
What I did is create a git hook 'post-merge' and added the following code:

```
#!/bin/sh
RED='\033[0;31m'
GREEN='\033[0;32m'
NC='\033[0m'

projectRoot="$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)"
solutionFile="solution.sln"

msBuild="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe"

echo -e "\n${RED}Restoring nuget packages for ${solutionFile}...${NC}"
./nuget.exe restore $projectRoot/development/$solutionFile
echo -e "${GREEN}Done restoring nuget packages for ${solutionFile}.${NC}\n"

echo -e "\n${RED}Building ${solutionFile}...${NC}"
"$msBuild"  $projectRoot/development/$solutionFile
echo -e "${GREEN}Done building ${solutionFile}.${NC}\n"

exit 1
```

I added exit 1 so that I can test my commands without actually pulling the project.

Now after I run nuget.exe on the solution path, it returns a msbuild auto-detection path, I want to use this path to locate msbuild.exe so I can run msbuild on the solution based on the version it's using.

How do I do this?
And if there's any way to improve or make this code better please let me know!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than capturing and parsing NuGet's output, you can [use VSWhere to find MSBuild](https://github.com/Microsoft/vswhere/wiki/Find-MSBuild).

From the wiki page:

> With Visual Studio 2017 Update 2 or newer installed, you can find vswhere at %ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe, or to make sure it's always available in your repo see [Installing](https://github.com/Microsoft/vswhere/wiki/Installing) for an option using NuGet.

powershell example that you'll need to adapt to Bash if you want to keep using bash

```
$path = vswhere -latest -products * -requires Microsoft.Component.MSBuild -property installationPath
if ($path) {
  $path = join-path $path 'MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe'
  if (test-path $path) {
    & $path $args
  }
}
```

EDIT: If you have the .NET Core SDK installed, you can just use `dotnet msbuild` to run msbuild, since installing the .NET Core SDK puts `dotnet.exe` on the path. The only real difference between using a Visual Studio MSBuild and the .NET Core MSBuild is that the extensions path will be different. But if your build doesn't depend on an MSBuild extension, then using `dotnet msbuild` works without having to find the path to an executable first.